# Storing results from simulated merMods in data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, lme4, mixed-models

Updated:

I'm trying to examine the variability in my parameter estimates from a `merMod` object by simulating known data and running the model 100 times. I'd like the result to be a data frame that looks like the following:

```
| simulation | intercept | est.x1 | est.x2 |
| ---------- | --------- | ------ | ------ |
| sim_study1 |.09        |.75     |.25     |
| sim_study2 |.10        |.72     |.21     |
| sim_study3 |NA         |NA      |NA      |
```

My code to generate multilevel data with a random intercept and 2 predictors is:

```
# note. this code block runs as expected, and if I run a lmer() call 
# on a simulated data set I get values that one would expect. 

gen_fake <- function(i, j){
    school <- rep(1:j)  
    person <- rep(1:i) # students nested in schools

    # parameters
    mu_a_true <- 0.10 # real intercept 
    sigma_a_true <- 0.10 # varince of intercept
    sigma_y_true <- 0.40
    b1_true <- .75
    b2_true <- .25

    # random intercept for schools  
    a_true <- rnorm(j, mu_a_true, sigma_a_true)

    # random data for predictors
    x1 <- rnorm(i, 0, 1)
    x2 <- rnorm(i, 0, 1)

    # outcome 
    y <- rnorm(i, a_true[school] + b1_true*x1 + b2_true*x2, sigma_y_true)

    return (data.frame(y, person, school, x1, x2))
}
```

I'm attempting to conduct a 100 simulations of a model, while generating new data each time. Note, I'm trying to implement tryCatch within the loop because with more complex models, where the model might not terminate normally, I'd like value returned in the table to be NA for parameters.

My code for this is as follows:

```
# create an empty data frame with names of parameters (there's probably
# a slicker way to do this within the loop where I can match names from 
# the model call)
sim_results <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=100, ncol=3, 
                      dimnames=list(c(),
                      c("intercept",
                      "est.x1", "est.x2"))),
                      stringsAsFactors=F)

# load library for analysis
library(lme4)

# conduct 100 simulations of the model generating fake data for each run
sim_study <- function (i, j, n.sims){
for (sim in 1:n.sims){
    fake_dat <- gen_fake(i, j)
    tryCatch({
        lmer_sim <- lmer(y ~ x1 + x2 + (1|school), data = fake_dat)
    }, error = function(e){
        return(NA)
    }) #return previous value of fm if error
    estimates <- rbind(fixef(lmer_sim))
    }
   sim_results[sim,] <- estimates
}

# run the simulation study
sim_study (1000,5,100)
```

The issue I am having is that the function only returns 1 row and it isn’t populating the empty data frame I made:

```
  (Intercept)        x1        x2
 [1,]  0.09659339 0.7746392 0.2325391
```

I'm unsure of the issue. Finally, any feedback you might have for how to make this work faster would also be appreciated, as I'd like to learn more about that issue. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: From the error, it seems `estimate` only has a length of 3 instead of 4 as you expected. What does the output of `fixef` (?) look like? It probably puts out a list or data.frame and one of the elements is itself a vector that needs to be split before you put it into your `sim_results` data frame.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my code using rbind on the `fixef` call. Now I appear to only get the first row of the simulation and my dimension names used in the creation of the data frame are not aligned with the output from the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bit of a forehead-slapper, but I think you just misplaced the loop brackets? This works for me:

```
sim_study <- function (i, j, n.sims){
  for (sim in 1:n.sims) {
    if (sim %% 10 == 0 ) cat(".\n")  ## print progress
    fake_dat <- gen_fake(i, j)
    tryCatch({
      lmer_sim <- lmer(y ~ x1 + x2 + (1|school), 
                       data = fake_dat)
    }, error = function(e){
      return(rep(NA,3))  ## return vector of correct length
    }) #return previous value of fm if error
    estimates <- rbind(fixef(lmer_sim))
    sim_results[sim,] <- estimates
  }
  return(sim_results)
}
```

A few more points:

- I'm not sure whether the `tryCatch()` logic works, since I didn't hit any errors (but I think it ought to be modified to return an object with the current length, as above)
- you could replace some of your `gen_fake` (not the generation of the predictors, but the generation of the response with the built-in `?simulate.merMod()`, but I don't think it would actually work any better (or worse)
- speeding this up significantly would be a bit of work/hacky. There is a `refit()` function that works quickly if only the predictor variable has changed, but it doesn't hold in this case.  You could use the tricks specified [here](https://rpubs.com/bbolker/fixed_refit) ...

Comment: Definite forehead-slapper. Thanks so much for the assistance here and your work with the package.